# scriptCurrencySymbol in V1 libs to mint assets

Tags: minting, plutus-starter, mintingpolicy

I'm using the latest Plutus-Stater project with this script

```
module FreeMinting where

import           Control.Monad          hiding (fmap)
import           Data.Aeson             (ToJSON, FromJSON)
import           Data.Text              (Text)
import           Data.Void              (Void)
import           GHC.Generics           (Generic)
import           Plutus.Contract        as Contract
import           Plutus.Trace.Emulator  as Emulator
import qualified PlutusTx
import           PlutusTx.Prelude       hiding (Semigroup(..), unless)
import           Ledger                 hiding (mint, singleton)
import           Ledger.Constraints     as Constraints
import qualified Ledger.Typed.Scripts   as Scripts
import           Ledger.Value           as Value
import           Playground.Contract    (printJson, printSchemas, ensureKnownCurrencies, stage, ToSchema)
import           Playground.TH          (mkKnownCurrencies, mkSchemaDefinitions)
import           Playground.Types       (KnownCurrency (..))
import           Prelude                (IO, Show (..), String)
import           Text.Printf            (printf)
import           Wallet.Emulator.Wallet

--ON-CHAIN

{-# INLINABLE freeMintingPolicy #-}
freeMintingPolicy :: () -> ScriptContext -> Bool
freeMintingPolicy _ _ = True

policy :: Scripts.MintingPolicy
policy = mkMintingPolicyScript $$(PlutusTx.compile [|| Scripts.wrapMintingPolicy freeMintingPolicy ||]) --unTypedValidator

curSymbol :: CurrencySymbol --aka PolicyID
curSymbol = scriptCurrencySymbol policy
```

But now **scriptCurrencySymbol** does not exists

Any tips on its substitute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
import Plutus.Script.Utils.V1.Scripts qualified as Scripts

-- ...

curSymbol = Scripts.scriptCurrencySymbol policy
```

You need to modify the `cabal.project` file to use `v0.1.0` of `plutus-apps` which has `Plutus.Script.Utils.V1.Scripts` module

```
-- Plutus apps revision from 2022-04-06
source-repository-package
  type: git
  location: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps.git
  tag: v0.1.0
```

Ref: [Plutus.Script.Utils.V1.Scripts](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/blob/main/plutus-script-utils/src/Plutus/Script/Utils/V1/Scripts.hs#L77) code

Comment: thanks a lot... still trying to get how documentation works with Cardano/Plutus ;)

Comment: my solution is copy the function which is not existed, and search on `input-output-hk` github (scope organization). There is some commit or code related to the function we need. in this case the function is `scriptCurrencySymbol`, then we infer to the correct module ;)